# Is it possible to pass arguments to a framework/library?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, frameworks, libraries

In my project I use different flags to run different code when dealing with multiple targets. Something like

```
#ifdef MY_FLAG
//do this
#else
//do this other
#endif
```

Now I'm on my way to take some code to an external library, but I don't want to compile different versions of the library for each flag, so the question is:

Is there a way to pass something like arguments that tells the library (or framework) from outside which code should run in a "global" manner?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing with `#ifdef` is establishing which code the compiler can see. So you're going to have to compile different versions for each flag, as libraries are linked against but are already compiled. I guess the question is more what you do with those on disk.

You can store multiple CPU architectures into a single static library. So any of those flags that are merely to do with whether you're targeting ARMv7, ARMv7s or i386 can be handled with a single library.

For the others you're probably going to have to produce different libraries. However that'll just be a matter of the shape of the disk footprint — you can use the project settings of any project you link against your libraries so that it links to a different version of the library depending on the build configuration.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have the framework provide some sort of initialization method or function that the user of the framework can call. This would tell the framework what "mode" it should run in. The client of the framework could call this at app startup.